# How to set selectedIndex when using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, html

I'm using AngularJS to grab a string array via an $http.get() and using it to populate a Select element. In my example, it populates fine with four valid options (and the annoying empty first option) but the selectedIndex of the Select element doesn't reflect the actual value of my $scope.opCall value. I've tried setting it in the view to 0, 1, 2, etc... without success. Selecting different values from the drowpdown via the UI does successfully update the UI, $scope.opCall & updateLogDisplay() works fine. In fact, everything works as expected less the Select element on the page not selecting the first valid option on initial load. It's empty. Am I clearly missing something or doing something wrong?

In the controller:

```
myApp.controller('LogViewCtrl', ['$scope','$http',function(scope,http){

  scope.getOperatorsUrl = '[redacted]';
  http.get(scope.getOperatorsUrl).
  then(function (data, status, statusText, headers, config)
  {
    scope.operators = data.data;
    scope.call = scope.operators[0] || ''; 
  });
```

In the template/html:

```
<select id="select1" 
        style="width: 150px;" 
        ng-model="opCall" 
        size='1'
        selectedIndex = "0"
        ng-change="updateLogDisplay();"
        ng-options="op for op in operators" 
        ng-init="opCall = operators[0]">
    <option value="" ng-show="false"></option>
</select>
```

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the NgModel to the first item in the in the controller instead of using NgInit in the view.

```
myApp.controller('LogViewCtrl', ['$scope','$http',function(scope,http){

  scope.getOperatorsUrl = '[redacted]';
  http.get(scope.getOperatorsUrl).
  then(function (data, status, statusText, headers, config)
  {
    scope.operators = data.data;
    scope.opCall= scope.operators[0] || ''; 
  });
```

Then in view:

```
<select id="select1" 
        style="width: 150px;" 
        ng-model="opCall" 
        ng-change="updateLogDisplay();"
        ng-options="op for op in operators">
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Embarrassingly, I had a mental type-o in the controller where I was setting scope.call to the scope.operators[0] instead of setting scope.opCall to it. Reading your code pointed that out to me! ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your *operators* array is being populated after the UI is build, so at the time of *ng-init*, I guess that your operators array is undefined.

You must populate the *opCall* model in the controller, once you know the *operators* array has been populated after the HTTP request (so within the *then*).

Comment: yes, I made a mental mistake and was setting _call_ instead of _opCall_ in the controller!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show your changes in HTML then call $scope.$apply(); in your then function part...[read here](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)..it updates variable bindings